# RabbitMQ "arguments" documentation

Tags: rabbitmq

When you create a queue, you can specify time-to-leave of the messages, deletion of the queue if it has not been used for some time etc.

Those parameters are passed via a dictionary ; is there a place where you can find the proper key-values list accepted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Arguments” are `amqp` `BasicProperties`

http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.2.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.2.4/com/rabbitmq/client/AMQP.BasicProperties.html

Some AMQP broker use the BasicProperties to implement their extensions, for example `Time-To-Live extension` is an RabbitMQ extension.

If you change the broker you lose this functionality.

Read http://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html to see the RabbitMQ extensions.

Anyway you can use the properties as you prefer, for example you can add an your custom key value.

The class http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases//rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/MessageProperties.html contains some pre-built BasicProperties.

Comment: This is in Java, but else it is the same as https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html under section "basic" ?

Comment: Nope, It's "table arguments" for example: 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.arguments.

you are right, the link is the java implemetation, where RMQ implents with BasicProperties class.

Comment: so if we are in Python, how do we know the argument names ?

Comment: Check here: http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.12/spec.html (class pika.spec.BasicProperties) for python.



For the custom fields it's the same, for example channel.queue_declare(queue='myqueue',
  arguments={
  'x-message-ttl' : 1000,
....

and here http://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html the extension names